# CFT: from States to Operators

Tags: string-theory, operators, hilbert-space, conformal-field-theory

I'm having trouble finding the general algorithm for moving from states to operators under the state-operator correspondence in a CFT. Does anyone have any hints as to how one might go about constructing this?

Comment: See, for example, section 6 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.07982 or chapter 2 of [Polchinski's string theory vol. 1](http://amzn.com/0521672279).

Comment: Thank you - these are excellent resources which I hadn't checked. Bonus credit if you can point me towards a non-path-integral argument (just out of academic interest). The usual non-path-integral arguments seem somewhat non-rigorous, relying as they do on bootstrap-like ideas.

Comment: @EdwardHughes, for non-path integral account you may consult http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01609130 and references therein. In particular, refer to Corollary 2.